# Vue router: How can a component load an outside url into the SPA?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Vue router: How can a component load an outside url into the SPA?

The outside content is a webpage located in the project folder.

This is similar to what `<iframe>` does.

The following component does not load the outside webpage and there are no browser console errors:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<template>
    <div id="someid">
        
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        
      }
    },
    
    methods: {
    
    },
    watch: {

    },
    components: {
     
    },
    created() {
          
    $("#someid").load("url");
 
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
    
</style>
```

Comment: Try moving your jQuery code to the `mounted` hook. Your `#someid` element won't exist in `created`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mounted()` life-cycle hook instead of `created()` for this purpose, because `created()` is the moment when the Vue instance is created and `mounted()` is the moment when DOM elements are ready.